# wwwroot/dist vs ClientApp/dist folder in .NETCore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

What is the difference between "wwwroot/dist" and "ClientApp/dist" folders after running this command and how to use them correctly?

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Comment: One difference is that the ClientApp folder is not visible for the outside world, while wwwroot is. So if you want to server your static content like js, css, image assets, etc, you should put it in wwwroot.

Comment: Exactly this. As long as you are using the `StaticFiles` middleware, then anything placed in the wwwroot directory can be accessed. The ClientApp/dist directory can be used for compiled (is that the right word?) SPA JavaScript if you're using one of the SPA templates or the JavaScript Services middleware

Comment: Thanks alot guys, but I can see that ClientApp contains main-server.js file, and wwwroot contains main-client.js file, so what is the difference between these files and how to use them correctly?

Comment: Typically you only want to to edit the ClientApp files when you make a change to code which you want to the SPA Services or WebPack to compile them. Otherwise, you should leave them as they are for now (until you gain a deeper understanding of what they're used for).

Comment: What I did understand for now that ClientApp is used for server side prerendering(Nodejs services), while wwwroot is for client side rendering, is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

The wwwroot/dist folder is basically an exposed folder that stores the compiled distributions of all pre-compiled javascript or scss code in the other parts of the project.

The ClientApp/dist folder stores all the compiled distributions of all the frontend framework classes/files within the ClientApp folder (i.e. AngularJS code transpiled docs).

.NET Core SPA apps usually route to the ClientApp/dist folder when performing Dependency injection on the SPA side of things.